# Query on reading bytes from "UTF-8" world to Java "char"

Tags: java, character-encoding, nio, bytebuffer

With the below code snippet given in this [link](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J5b_IO.html),

```
byte[] bytes = {0x00, 0x48, 0x00, 0x69, 0x00, 0x2C,
                      0x60, (byte)0xA8, 0x59, 0x7D, 0x00, 0x21};  // "Hi,您好!"

Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
// Encode from UCS-2 to UTF-8
// Create a ByteBuffer by wrapping a byte array
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
// Create a CharBuffer from a view of this ByteBuffer
CharBuffer cb = bb.asCharBuffer();
```

Using `wrap()` method, "The new buffer will be backed by the given byte array", Here we do not have any encoding from byte to other format, it just placed byte array in a buffer.

Can you please help me understand, what exactly are we doing when we say `bb.asCharBuffer()` in the above code?`cb` is similar to array of characters. Because `char` is UTF-16 in Java, Using `asCharBuffer()` method, Are we considering every 2bytes in `bb` as `char`? Is this the right approach? If no, Please help me with right approach.

Edit:
I tried this program as recommended by Meisch below,

```
byte[] bytes = {0x00, 0x48, 0x00, 0x69, 0x00, 0x2C,
                0x60, (byte)0xA8, 0x59, 0x7D, 0x00, 0x21};  // "Hi,您好!"

        Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
        CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
        CharBuffer cb = decoder.decode(bb);
```

which gives exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.decode(Unknown Source)
    at TestCharSet.main(TestCharSet.java:16)
```

Please help me, am stuck up here!!!

*Note : am using java 1.6*

Answer (score 3):

You ask: “Because `char` is UTF-16 in Java, using `asCharBuffer()` method, are we considering every 2 bytes in `bb` as `char`?”

The answer to that question is yes.  Your understanding is correct.

Your next question is: “Is this the right approach?”

If you are just trying to demonstrate how the ByteBuffer, CharBuffer and Charset classes work, it's acceptable.

However, when you are coding an application, you will never write code like that.  To begin with, there is no need for a byte array;  you can represent the characters as a literal String:

```
String s = "Hi,\u60a8\u597d!";
```

If you want to convert the string to UTF-8 bytes, you can simply do this:

```
byte[] encodedBytes = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

If you're still using Java 6, you would do this instead:

```
byte[] encodedBytes = s.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

**Update:** Your byte array represents chars in the UTF-16BE (big-endian) encoding.  Specifically, your array has exactly two bytes per character.  That is not a valid UTF-8 encoded byte sequence, which is why you're getting the MalformedInputException.

When characters are encoded as UTF-8 bytes, each character will be represented with 1 to 4 bytes.  For your second code fragement to work, the array must be:

```
byte[] bytes = {
    0x48, 0x69, 0x2c,                       // ASCII chars are 1 byte each
    (byte) 0xe6, (byte) 0x82, (byte) 0xa8,  // U+60A8
    (byte) 0xe5, (byte) 0xa5, (byte) 0xbd,  // U+597D
    0x21
};
```

When converting from bytes to chars, my earlier statement still applies:  You don't need ByteBuffer or CharBuffer or Charset or CharsetDecoder.  You *can* use those classes, but usually it's more succinct to just create a String:

```
String s = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

If you want a CharBuffer, just wrap the String:

```
CharBuffer cb = CharBuffer.wrap(s);
```

You may be wondering when it is appropriate to use a CharsetDecoder directly.  You would do that if the bytes are coming from a source which is not under your control, and you have good reason to believe it may not contain properly UTF-8 encoded bytes.  Using an explicit CharsetDecoder allows you to customize how invalid bytes will be handled.

Comment: your program is converting from Java `char` to `UTF-8`, my query is asking the opposite, am getting bytes from `UTF-8` world and then converting those bytes to Java `char`.

Comment: I was trying to address your original questions.  I've updated my answer based on your edit.

Comment: 1) `System.out.println(s);` with your above two lines of code, the output is `Hi,??!` which i guess is wrong. 2) If bytes are coming from source, where i dont the charset encoding, can i handle that situation as well?

Answer (score 0):

I just had a look at the sources, it boils down to two bytes from the byte buffer being combined into one character. The order in which the two bytes are used depends on the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), default ist big-endian.

Another approach using nio classes than what I wrote in the comments would be to use the CharsetDecoder.decode() method.

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
CharBuffer cb = decoder.decode(bb);
```

Comment: nio design is not so readable. this byte buffer may come from UTF-8 world(say), How do we take two bytes and convert to character? UTF-8 is variable length from 1-4 bytes

Comment: You can't do this with ByteBuffer and CharBuffer, these do stupid 2-byte operations. You might try an InputStreamReader: `new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes), charset)`

Comment: am actually not clear, what is the approach to read bytes from UTF-8 world and make it available as UTF-16 `char` in Java, how do i do that?

Comment: as I wrote, create an InputStreamReader as I showed, and then you can call for example it's `read()`method which gives you a utf-16 (int), or wrap in a BufferedReader to read whole lines.